# Dependency restrictions without modules

Tags: java, android, architecture, dependencies

Let's say there is an architecture like

```
Layer App
Layer Foo
Layer Bar
```

Now all layers are in different packages but in the same module (*I am looking for a setup where all Layers can live within the same module*)

Here is the usage restriction

```
Layer App should only know (and use) Layer Foo and Layer Bar
Layer Foo should only know (and use) Layer Bar
Layer Bar should not know any of the above layers
```

**How can i achieve this dependency restrictions without creating 3 different modules and declare those dependencies in the `gradle` build script.**

Comment: Take a look here: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl

Comment: Generally speaking, this is achieved with strictly following imposed rules, self-control and/or code reviews. A tool might be useful as well though.

Comment: @TomVanRossom this is brilliant. Do you know an alternative for kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Though not foolproof, you can do something like this to help control things :

Declare a class for each layer representing the API for that layer (e.g Foo). Make a generic constructor, such that, it takes an instance of the API class(es) of any valid calling layers. If you then are diligent enough to always access layers through the API class then you should be ok.

e.g. in ***pseudo-code*** :

```
class Foo {

  public Foo<T>(T caller) {
    if caller is App {
      return
    }
    throw new Exception("invalid call to layer")
  }

  ObjA NewObjA()
  int SomeFuncB()
}

class App {

  private Foo foo

  public App<T>(T caller) {
    if caller is Foo or caller is Bar {
      throw new Exception("invalid call to layer")
    }
    foo = new Foo(this)
  }

  ObjC NewObjC()
  int SomeFuncD()
}
```

You could even make the classes from each layer inner classes of the API class.